# gulp. Последовательное выполнение функций используя Promise

Tags: gulp, promise

Пытаюсь на gulp'е выполнить две задачи последовательно. Вот мой gulpfile.js:

```
const {src, dest, watch, parallel, series} = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

async function concatToLibsScss(){
    await src([
        'node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css',
        'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('_libs.scss'))
    .pipe(dest('app/scss'));
    return Promise;
}

async function scssToOneMinCss(){
    await src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        overrideBrowserslist: ['last 8 versions']
    }))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(dest('app/css'));
    return Promise;
}

async function deff(){
     await concatToLibsScss();
     await scssToOneMinCss();
     return Promise;
}

exports.default = deff;
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
$ gulp
[03:37:59] Using gulpfile D:\0MyAll\gitProjects\mygulpstart\gulpfile.js
[03:37:59] Starting 'default'...
[03:37:59] Finished 'default' after 27 ms

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: app\scss\style.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: libs.
        on line 2 of app/scss/style.scss
>> @import "libs";
   ^

    at options.error (D:\0MyAll\gitProjects\mygulpstart\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at DestroyableTransform.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:461:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.onerror (D:\0MyAll\gitProjects\mygulpstart\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:640:52)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
    at onwriteError (D:\0MyAll\gitProjects\mygulpstart\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:449:12)
    at onwrite (D:\0MyAll\gitProjects\mygulpstart\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:470:11)
    at WritableState.onwrite (D:\0MyAll\gitProjects\mygulpstart\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:180:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.afterTransform (D:\0MyAll\gitProjects\mygulpstart\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:93:3)
    at errorM (D:\0MyAll\gitProjects\mygulpstart\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:118:12)
    at Object.callback (D:\0MyAll\gitProjects\mygulpstart\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:127:16)
```

Суть ошибки в следующем. Я пытаюсь последовательно вызвать две функции: сначала concatToLibsScss, а после ее завершения concatToLibsScss. Но, несмотря на все мои старания, вторя функция выполняется не дождавшись результатов выполнения первой, которые ей нужны для успешного завершения. Вопрос: как добиться чтобы вторая функция выполнялась после того как результаты работы первой полностью готовы? Почему await не дожидается окончания выполнения вызываемой справа от него функции? 
Версия gulp: 4.0.2.

Comment: сколько я вопросов видел по gulp но ни разу не видел ответов ....

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gulp

Answer (score 0):

Первое что нужно помнить: async функция возвращает Promise ! Изучи более вдумчиво этот вопрос (в инете полно материала по теме)

```
concatToLibsScss().then({
scssToOneMinCss().then({
   console.log('Ура выполнилось последовательно !')
});
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но то что вы написали выдает ошибку `scssToOneMinCss().then({ SyntaxError: Unexpected token . `
 Видимо синтаксис не верный. Я вот так написал 
`function deff(cb){ 
    concatToLibsScss().then(scssToOneMinCss()); 
    cb(); 
}` 
Но все равно это не привело к тому, чтобы эти функции выполнялись последовательно. Видимо сами эти функции у меня не верные. Не тот Promise может быть возвращают.

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким еще способом удалось добиться, чтоб задачи выполнялись последовательно.

```
const {src, dest, watch, parallel, series} = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');


function concatToLibsScss(){
    return src([
        'node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css',
        'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('_libs.scss'))
    .pipe(dest('app/scss'));

}

function scssToOneMinCss(){
    return src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        overrideBrowserslist: ['last 8 versions']
    }))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(dest('app/css'));
}

exports.default = series(concatToLibsScss, scssToOneMinCss);
```